# I am using a mail code in asp.net . it is working fine locally but doesn't work online on godaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have used this code before in many websites and there it worked fine but this time there is some problem. The biggest problem is that this code is not throwing any exception.

```
            try
        {
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress sendr = new MailAddress("admission@mpgilko.com");
            MailAddress receiver = new MailAddress("admission@mpgilko.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                                                                  delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                         X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                                                                  { return true; };
            client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
            client.Port = 25;
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            //client.Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
            //client.Port = 587;
            //client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admission@mpgilko.com", "[Password]");
            m.From = sendr;
            m.To.Add(receiver);

            m.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            m.Subject = "Enquiry on www.mpgilko.com";
            m.Body = "Name: " + name.Value.ToString() + "\n Mobile: " + mobile.Value.ToString() + "\n Course: " + course.Value + "\n City: " + city.Value.ToString() + "\n Query: " + query.Value.ToString();
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(m);
            return 1;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblmsg.InnerText = ex.Message.ToString();
            return 0;
        }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: maybe you can capture the traffic and analyze?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if go daddy disables traffic to port 25. Try switching to ssl/tls and some other port. BTW: https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2998/unable-to-send-over-port-25-with-godaddy.aspx

Comment: `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` are `IDisposable`'s.  You should make use of the `using(){}` block for them.

Comment: tried with port 80 and 3535 . still not able to send any mail.